# Do gems have secondary effects?

Tags: torchlight-2

Do elemental gems in Torchlight 2 have secondary effects other than direct elemental damage or elemental armor?

I am referring to poison, fire, ice and electric gem and try to understand which of them are better-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each element has its own attack side effect, which has a chance to occur on each hit.  Some of them are hinted at in the loading screen tips.

- Ice attacks have a chance to Freeze, which slows down movement, attack, and cast speed by 33% for a few seconds.
- Poison attacks have a chance to Poison, which reduces damage and all armor by 33%
- Electric attacks have a chance to Shock, which causes the afflicted enemy to emit electric bolts that damage more enemies every time it is hit.
- Fire attacks have a chance to Burn, which is fire damage over time that ignores armor.

Note that these all have a chance to occur on elemental attacks from *any* source, including skills.  Elemental gems give you these effects only as a direct consequence of giving your weapon an additional elemental attack type.

Comment: Doesn't freeze also reduce attack speed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they don't have any further effects. The idea behind finding the right one for you and your character should be the rest of your skilltree/items. This is because the gem's dmg is affected by skills/items. As an example: if you skilled 40% poison dmg, you'll get 40% more dmg from poison gems in contrast to the other elements.

If that does not really answer your question, feel free to give me further details ;)

edit: see comment - I forget about so much because of all these new games :D

Comment: I am asking it because some friends told me "Put poison gems because there are chances that they poisonous enemies", or "Use ice gems because they could slow down them sometimes", etc. but I didnd't find any reference in game, so I am not sure if they are wrong or not.

Comment: Ah well your friends are right: 1) Poison Gems give chance to put poison debuff on target which reduces dmg dealt by target 2) fire gems put fire debuff on target, makes them burn for additional dmg 3) lightn. gems give chance to paralyze target which ccs them for a certain amount of time 4) frost gem add a chance to deepfreeze target to slowdown movement (not sure but i think atckspeed aswell)